# Android Studio design editor doen't show a toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar

Could someone help me? Android studio design editor doesn't show a toolbar. But when I start the application I a toolbar appears. Please see a screenshot.
How do I add a toolbar to an editor so that I could add search button to it?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.StarWars">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: it is Russian language segment. Please use English one or translate to Russian.

Comment: Редактор дизайна Андроид Studio не отображает Toolbar. Но когда я запускаю приложение, Toolbar есть. Посмотрите скриншот. Как добавить Toolbar в редактор Андроид Studio, чтобы я мог добавить на него кнопку поиска?

Comment: Смените стиль на NoActionBar и добавьте Toolbar в разметку экрана.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.